# Find max row value using .shift and .apply in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2.001, 4.001, 8.001, 0.001],
                   'B': [2.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001],
                   'C': [11.001, 12.001, 11.001, 8.001],
                   'D': [12.001, 23.001, 12.001, 8.021],
                   'E': [11.001, 24.001, 18.001, 8.0031]})
```

I can find the max value (in each row) between columns A, B, E and E (shifted by -1) using the below-mentioned method:

```
df["e_shifted"] =  df["E"].shift(-1)
df.apply(lambda x: max(x['A'], x['B'], x['E'], x['e_shifted']),axis = 1)
```

But this creates a temporary column (i.e. e_shifted) in the dataframe.

How can .apply () and shift(-1) be used together without creating a temporary column?

For example, using the below code:

```
df.apply(lambda x: max(x['A'], x['B'], x['E'], x['E'].shift(-1)),axis = 1)
```

gives an error as below:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift'
```

As per the solution provided by @Corralien(shown below), the code handles the shifting of a single column:

```
out = df.assign(E_shift=df['E'].shift(-1))[['A', 'B', 'E', 'E_shift']].max(axis=1)
```

But can the solution provided by @Corralien be modified to handle the shifting of multiple columns?

For example:

```
out = df.assign(E_shift=df['E'].shift(-1), A_shift=df['A'].shift(-1))[['A', 'B', 'E', 'E_shift', 'A_Shift']].max(axis=1)
```

Doing so gives the following error:

```
KeyError: "['A_Shift'] not in index"
```

Solution (after @mozway pointed out the error in typo):

```
out = df.assign(E_shift=df['E'].shift(-1), A_shift=df['A'].shift(-1))[['A', 'B', 'E', 'E_shift', 'A_shift']].max(axis=1)
```

Comment: Why are you avoiding a temporary column? Performance?

Comment: Mainly because the dataframe is written back to a database, thus wanted to restrict the columns in the dataframe

Comment: You're mentioning several columns to be shifted, can you please be explicit and provide the exact (final) logic as [edit] to the question?

Comment: @mozway: I was also looking at any solution that can be altered to shift multiple columns

Comment: @PrateekDaniels and we're happy to provide that, but please be explicit

Comment: "*But can the solution provided by @Corralien be modified to handle the shifting of multiple columns?*" -> yes it can and `df.assign(E_shift=df['E'].shift(-1), A_shift=df['A'].shift(-1))[['A', 'B', 'E', 'E_shift', 'A_Shift']].max(axis=1)` does that. But it looks like you're not happy with it, please provide an explicit **numerical example** that demonstrates **why**. Just repeating that "*it doesn't work*" is not enough to explain what you want.

Comment: I am getting  a KeyError: "['A_Shift'] not in index" when I do that

Comment: because you used a different case `A_shift` ≠ `A_Shift`.

Comment: Sincere apologies :)  and thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than avoiding creating an extra column, you should avoid using `apply` on each row of your dataframe, which is very slow. In your case, you can use `assign` to create a temporary column that will not affect your original dataframe then use a vectorized [`max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html):

```
out = df.assign(E_shift=df['E'].shift(-1))[['A', 'B', 'E', 'E_shift']].max(axis=1)
print(out)

# Output
0    24.0010
1    24.0010
2    18.0010
3     8.0031
dtype: float64
```

Comment: The issue is, say if there are three columns that need to be shifted, how could we alter this ?

out = df.assign(E_shift=df['E'].shift(-1), A_shift=df['A'].shift(-1))[['A', 'B', 'E', 'E_shift', 'A_Shift']].max(axis=1)


Tried doing, that and doesn't work

Comment: How doesn't it work? Please be explicit and provide an example that demonstrate how this fails and what should be the expected output?

Comment: @mozway: 
out = df.assign(E_shift=df['E'].shift(-1), A_shift=df['A'].shift(-1))[['A', 'B', 'E', 'E_shift', 'A_Shift']].max(axis=1)

Comment: This doesn't demonstrate anything. Please edit the question and give a clear example (input, exact expected output)

Answer (score 1):

Using vectorized operations as mentioned by @ Corralien in Pandas is generally more efficient than using apply on each row. However if u want to use apply function, you can use the shift function outside the apply function and then apply the max function along the columns.
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2.001, 4.001, 8.001, 0.001],
                   'B': [2.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001],
                   'C': [11.001, 12.001, 11.001, 8.001],
                   'D': [12.001, 23.001, 12.001, 8.021],
                   'E': [11.001, 24.001, 18.001, 8.0031]})

# Shift the 'E' column by -1
shifted_E = df['E'].shift(-1)

# Use apply along the columns
result = df.apply(lambda x: max(x['A'], x['B'], x['E'], shifted_E[x.name]), axis=1)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code fails because you're trying to "shift" a float value instead of a pandas series. Inside the lambda function `x` assumes the value of each row (pd.Series). So when you reference `x['E']` you get a float value corresponding to the value in column E in a specific row. The `apply` method iterates over each row of `df`.

What you're looking for is

```
from numpy import max as np_max    
pd.concat([df['A'], df['B'], df['E'], df['E'].shift(-1)], axis=1).apply(np_max, axis=1)
```

Here you're creating a temporary dataframe with shifted values for E using `pd.concat` and then applying a straightforward `np.max` on axis 1. You could also just apply python's built-in `max` as well depending on your preferences.

About your requirement of not having temporary columns - this is where wrapping your logic in a function/method will help. You could define a function/method to perform this operation as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import List
import numpy as np


def row_wise_max(df: pd.DataFrame, cols: List[str], cols_to_shift: List[str], shift_cols_by: List[int]) -> pd.Series:
    assert len(cols_to_shift) == len(shift_cols_by)
    for col, shift_by in zip(cols_to_shift, shift_cols_by):
        df[f"{col}_shifted"] = df[col].shift(shift_by)
    result = df[cols + [f"{x}_shifted" for x in cols_to_shift]].apply(np.max, axis=1)
    return result
```

Use it as follows:

```
# define your 'df' here    
row_wise_max(df, cols=['A', 'B', 'E'], cols_to_shift=['E'], shift_cols_by=[-1])
```

Effectively you're letting the intermediate stages be handled in the local scope of a function rather than in your global scope. Your original `df` is effectively unaltered.

Answer (score 0):

One Liner Solution

```
result = df.apply(lambda x: max(x['A'], x['B'], x['E'], df['E'].shift(-1)[x.name]), axis=1)

#output
0    24.0010
1    24.0010
2    18.0010
3     8.0031
dtype: float64
```

Comment: That's a bad approach since it would recalculate the full shift for each row (O(n**2) complexity) and fail if the index has duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

```
result = df[['A', 
'B','E']].max(axis=1).combine_first(df['E'].shift(-1))

print(result)
```

In this example, df[['A', 'B', 'E']].max(axis=1) calculates the maximum value for each row for columns 'A', 'B', and 'E'. The combine_first() function is then used to fill missing values (NaN) with the values from the shifted 'E' column.

Comment: This is incorrect. `df[['A','B','E']].max(axis=1)` doesn't yield any NaN, so the `.combine_first(df['E'].shift(-1))` is not doing anything. And if it was, this wouldn't be the correct logic. E_shift must be compared to the other columns in the `max` step.